# How to configure Entity Framework connection in this complicated setup

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

Lets say you have 1 web app and your running the same code base for each of the 50 states. Due to legalities of storing the data each state has to have their own separate database even though their all identical except for their name and the actual data. To keep the application in a single code base. you have 50 instances of the app on a web server each with a different connection string in their web.config.

Then you want to use EF 5 code first with migraitons.
I want EF 5 to use 1 specified connection string. to an existing database. I don't want to have a connection string for each object in my model. like...

```
<add name="ProductsContext" connectionString=".....
<add name="UsersContext" connectionString=".....
<add name="LocationsContext" connectionString=".....
```

I want to have 1 connection string like

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString=".....
```

How do I do this?

Also if each object in my model needs to be part of a dbcontext is it better to have them in separate contexts like tutorials show or can/should they all be in the same one which would allow me to just have a "default context".  How many contexts should you have?

If I let EF use the connection factory and create 3 contexts it tries to create 3 databases.

Note I cannot specify the connection programatically because each copy of the app connects to a differently named database.

I'm really getting confused about EF wanting a db for each object in my model. Also if theirs a way to have 1 code base access 50 separate databases and know which one to be in on start up without any user interaction that would be helpful too. Currently using separately hosted instances of the same code with different web-config files is a bitch to maintain when it comes time to update the code on the webserver.

suggestions? solutions? best practices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each context class that you define creates a new model, in the vast majority of cases you will only need 1 model and thus 1 context class per app. Also if there are navigation properties between entities in different contexts they won't work as expected.
This way you would only need 1 line in each of the web.config files to specify the connection string.

Take a look at this tutorial on how to create a model with several entity types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542